# Running tests from directory not in class path

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, junit5

I am trying to run tests that are in  a jar file (sr/java/main/test/jarfile.jar directory ).
The launcher does not find any test.  From intellij, in source of project when i runTesT is all ok, so no problem in actual tests. 
TestProject:

```
 Test_Road
 ├── src
 │   ├── test
 │   │      ├── java
 │   │      └── package_test
 │   └──resource          │
 │                        └── ConfigurationControllerTest.java
 └── pom.xml
```

pom.xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>it.almaviva</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestSuite</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.20131108.vaadin1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>

        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```
public class ConfigurationControllerTest {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ConfigurationControllerTest.class);

    private static Properties properties = PropertyUtil.getProperties("/test.properties");

       @Test
    public void smartRoadRegistryTest(){
        String endpoint = properties.getProperty("smart-road.api.configuration-controller.endpoint.registry");

        try {
            expect().
                    statusCode(200).
                    contentType(ContentType.JSON).
            when().
                    get(endpoint);
        } catch(AssertionError e){
            log.error("Smart Road Registry test has failed ... \n");
            Assertions.fail(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

If i run smartRoadRegistryTest method it work well.

Now i have create a new project TestSuiteLoader where i load jar inspect class and method with @Test and after i run a method called.

```
src
 └── main
      └── java
            ├── packageRunTest
            │      └── TestsuiteApplication.java
            └── pakageTest
            └──TestClass.jar
```

My function is this:

```
public void runOne(String jar_file,String class_name, String test_name,SummaryGeneratingListener listener) {

        File file = new File("src\\main\\java\\test\\"+ jar_file);
        URL[] urls = {new URL("jar:file:" + file + "!/")};
        URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);

        Class cls=cl.loadClass(class_name);
        Method m=cls.getMethod(test_name);
        LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
                .selectors(selectMethod(cls,m))
                .build();

        Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create();
        launcher.registerTestExecutionListeners(listener);
        launcher.execute(request);
        TestExecutionSummary summary = listener.getSummary();

        StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
        summary.printTo(new PrintWriter(out));
        System.out.println(out);
    }
```

when i run it in main as:

```
this.runOne("TestSuite.jar","SmartRoadApiTest.ConfigurationControllerTest","smartRoadRegistryTest", new SummaryGeneratingListener());
```

In console i read:

Test run finished after 63 ms

```
[         1 containers found      ]
[         0 containers skipped    ]
[         1 containers started    ]
[         0 containers aborted    ]
[         1 containers successful ]
[         0 containers failed     ]
[         0 tests found           ]
[         0 tests skipped         ]
[         0 tests started         ]
[         0 tests aborted         ]
[         0 tests successful      ]
[         0 tests failed          ]
```

0 Test Found!!

my pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>it.anas.TestSuiteLoader</groupId>
    <artifactId>testsuite</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>testsuite</name>
    <description>Servizi per Caricamento Test Suite</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.12</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>4.12.0-M4</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.2</version>
                </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Thanks Regards
Giuseppe

Comment: By far most easiest solution is to have your jar in your local repository (e.g. via mvn install:install-file) and add it to your pom.xml with test-scope.

Comment: i'm on intellij how add jar in your local repository?

Comment: where is the jar coming from?

Comment: Either try to achieve your goal with running w/o Maven first: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-console-launcher or stay on the Maven-way of unit (Surefire) and integration (Failsafe) testing like I already proposed here: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/2215#issuecomment-599081491

Comment: First I would suggest to reconsider your pom file cause in both pom examples you are mixing different versions of JUnit Jupiter together...furthermore you have added testng to the concert (spring boot example).. I strongly recommend to decide for which testing framework you would like to but only one...If you need a different framework (for example testng) than make a separate modules otherwise you will get in trouble ...

Comment: I want use only junit5... I must change pom.xml in test project or in testLoader? I want use only junit5.. how change the pom.xml? Jar is in test package.. you can help me plz?

Comment: Sormuras ok but how there is an example? I kist run from java application ni command line

Comment: Select one of those starters: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples -- they provide good starting points. Add one thing after another of your use-case and keep the bar green.

Comment: i have doing this but dont work! i found Test it but dont start!